# How to PInvoke this C++ function?

Tags: c#, .net, string, char, pinvoke

I have the following function:

```
bool __declspec(dllexport) COMS_HL7QueryAnswer(char *szZone,char* szMessage, char** o_szAnswer)
```

And I'm PInvoking it from C# like this:

```
public static extern bool COMS_HL7QueryAnswer(string szZone,string szMessage, out StringBuilder szAnswer);
```

It's working in Windows 2003 but I'm getting access violation exceptions in W2008 and looks like they happen in the boundary of the PInvoke. Any help will be great.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Looks like the AccessViolationException happens in the PInvoke boundary because:

1. I don't have a callstack other than the C# function.
2. When I go with the debugger I can F10 until the last C++ function and when I exit the } then I go to the C# exception handler.

Comment: Please explain the statement **looks like they happen in the boundary**.  Addtional information how it is failed exactly would be helpful.

Comment: Beyond the fact your signature is not valid, your calling convention also does not match, you might want to resolve that.

Comment: @Ramhound: Can you explain that in more deep please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use

```
[DllImport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool COMS_HL7QueryAnswer(string szZone,string szMessage, out IntPtr szAnswer);
```

Because p/invoke has no idea how to correctly free `*o_szAnswer`, you' need to keep the pointer and pass it to the correct deallocation function yourself, after retrieving the data.

If you are allowed to change the C++ side, there are a number of things you can do to make this more p/invoke-friendly.  Or you can use a C++/CLI layer.

Comment: Why the CLR don't free *szAnswer when the StringBuilder is GC'ed? Well, maybe *szAnswer is something global and this should not happen right?

Comment: @SoMoS: `*o_szAnswer` was assigned to the address of some buffer inside the C++ code.  The CLR can read from that buffer into a `StringBuilder`, but then it doesn't know how to free the buffer.  So either it tries to free it and guesses the wrong deallocation function, and you get an access violation, or it does nothing, and you get a memory leak.

Comment: @SoMoS: I meant `*o_szAnswer`, the C-style string.  Sorry if that caused you any confusion.  The `StringBuilder` object gets garbage collected, but the data isn't in a `StringBuilder` when it leaves C++.

Comment: It also helps if the CallingConvention is set to match the C++ code.

Comment: Great, now it works but I don't know how to free the data. It is created with new inside C++. The methods of Marshal talk about things I don't understand like HGLobal  and so on ...

Comment: @SoMoS: You'll need another function exported from the C++ DLL in order to free it.  And surely it's allocated with `new[]` (the array version), right?

Comment: @Ramhound: We don't know for sure what the C++ code is using, without seeing the compiler options.  But you're probably right that there's a mismatch.  Updated answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is leaking memory.  Yes, W2003 will silently ignore the pinvoke marshaller's attempt to release the string.  W2008 has a much stricter memory manager and won't put up with it, it triggers an AccessViolation.  You can keep leaking memory with out IntPtr and Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi().  If you can fix the C code then allocating the string buffer with CoTaskMemAlloc() will solve the problem, the pinvoke marshaller uses CoTaskMemFree().

A real fix is char* instead of char** so that the caller can pass a buffer to be filled with the string.  StringBuilder without *out* from C#.  With an extra argument that gives the Capacity so you won't corrupt the garbage collected heap by accident when the string doesn't fit.

Comment: With `out IntPtr`, his code has the correct pointer to pass to the deallocation function.